# jquery appended html is not detecting javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, append

sorry if my question deosnt make sense, but thats the best way i can put it, i have this jquery script that when user clicks the login link, it appends the html form to do so, which works fine, but the appended(login-form) uses jquery to log into the site, but it deosnt seem to detect the javascript,

oppose to when i put the login form without appending, just normally on the page, it works fine, it detects the javascript, but not when appended.

i hope you understand what i just said thank :))

the code is a bit long, but i shortened it for illustartion purposes.

http://jsfiddle.net/YHCwM/1/

Comment: Having offered an answer, it's worth noting that JS Fiddle doesn't really implement Ajax (or doesn't *seem* to), so I'm not seeing any elements being dynamically added to your page in the first place. Do you have a test-site you can demo your problem? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is your sequence of events:

1. DocumentLoad fires
2. Attach a `submit()` handler to an element that doesn't exist yet - so no handlers are added
3. User clicks a button which adds the element to the page

You can either fix this by using **[live events](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** or changing the order. (Live wireup for the `submit` event is new as of jQuery 1.4.1 IIRC).

```
$('#regForm2').live('submit', function(e){});
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because normally jQuery binds events to elements already in the DOM when the scripts first run. Elements added later need to be bound differently, often using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Instead of:

```
$('#elementAddedLater').click(function(){/*....*/});
```

try:

```
$('#elementAddedLater').live('click',function(){/*....*/});
```

The linked-function name, above, gives a run-through of the other events that can be bound via `.live()`

As @Pointy notes, below, it's also worth looking at [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which seems to offer much the same functionality as `.live()`, but more concisely and clearly.

Comment: Also worth looking at is the `.delegate()` function, which is in some ways superior to `.live()`; it's certainly more flexible.